# Error in MVC unit test for controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a code block in my unit test project as below

```
IEnumerable<Product> result = (IEnumerable<Product>)controller.List(2).Model;
```

it produce error

```
Error   1   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' could be found ..
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If action returns view, cast it to [ViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
((ViewResult)(IEnumerable<Product>)controller.List(2)).Model
```

Comment: No need to cast it, just change the action to public ViewResult List(int param)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @archil will throw an exception at run time:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Product]'.
```

The correct cast is:

```
IEnumerable<Product> result = (IEnumerable<Product>)((ViewResult)controller.List(2)).Model;
```

Or simply, change the return type of the action to a `ViewResult` instead of an `ActionResult`:

```
public ViewResult List(int param)
```

And in the unit test use:

```
IEnumerable<Product> result = (IEnumerable<Product>)controller.List(2).Model;
```